# Destructuring in php

Tags: javascript, php, destructuring

Is it possible to use javascript like destructuring to create an associative array from variables with variable names as keys in PHP... in javascript I can do

```js
 const fn = (name, age, purpose) => {
    return {name, age, purpose}
 }
 fn("Akins", 23, "Greatness") // {name: "Akins", age: 23, purpose: "Greatness"}
```

Currently I am stick to repetitive way

```php
function fn($name, $age, $purpose) {
     return [
         'name'    => $name,
         'age'     => $age,
         'purpose' => $purpose
     ];
}
```

Can anyone help, it will save me a whole lot of typing?

Comment: `$array = [0, 1, 2]; list($a, $b, $c) = $array;` Now `$a` will contain 0, `$b` 1 etc. You may want to have a look at this website that lists all the other possibilities: https://stitcher.io/blog/array-destructuring-with-list-in-php

Comment: @icecub Doesn't seem like the thing the OP is talking about. What you've linked creates a list of variables from an array. OP is looking for the opposite - taking a list of variables and creating an array.

Comment: `compact` seems to be what you're looking for?

Comment: Isn't this what [compact](https://www.php.net/compact) is for?

Comment: @icecub list() will not do it

Comment: Ah well, was worth a shot :) Hence the reason I commented and didn't answer. Wasn't entirely sure if it would help

Comment: The problem with the question is, that the text is talking about destructuring, and then having an example of shorthand property names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to create your own function for this, one already exists:

```
$name    = "Jason";
$age     = 25;
$purpose = "To have fun?";

$person  = compact('name', 'age', 'purpose');

print_r($person);
```

Ouptut:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Jason
    [age] => 25
    [purpose] => To have fun?
)
```

Answer (score 2):

That is your answer

```php
function fn($name, $age, $purpose) {
    return compact('name', 'age', 'purpose');
}
```

**compact — Create array containing variables and their values** 
compact() looks for a variable with that name in the current symbol table and adds it to the output array such that the variable name becomes the key and the contents of the variable become the value for that key.